# Sequelize Count if greater

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, sequelize.js

I want to count multiple columns grouped by "Vendor_name" column

```
const vendorSummary = await IndexData.findAll({
  group: 'Vendor_name',
  attributes: [
    'Vendor_name',
    [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('Item_number')), 'Total'],
    [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('Images')), 'Images'],
    [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('Technicals_PDF')), 'PDF'],
  ],
});
```

At the moment Total is equal to Images and PDFS count. I dont know how to add where clausule
so it counts everything in totals and only those in images and pdfs where its value is > 0.
Sum cannot be used as some entries have values > 1 and the result would not be what i want.

Comment: You can try `iif` function https://stackoverflow.com/a/70099691/2956135.  or `case when` if you have lower version

Comment: @Emma Thanks, i have actually decided to skip sequelize and just wrote raw query that did what I wanted because I couldn't figure it out :P